# How do I make the Pyglet media queue continue playing?

Tags: python, pyglet

I have multiple songs being loaded and queued up in my player, however the player stops after the first song and I have to manually force the next song using next_source() though from the documentation I believe it should be automatic.

I'm running Python 3.7.1 and Pyglet 1.3.2, I have scoured the documentation and tried different methods of queuing the data. I have looked into making sure the file is playing completely, though I'm unsure if playback is ever ending on the first song.

```py
chosenDirectory = ""
cSong = ""
cSongIndex = 0
player = pyglet.media.Player()
songList = []


def chooseDirectory():
    global chosenDirectory
    chosenDirectory = tk.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/")
    lbl.configure(text=chosenDirectory)
    listBox.delete("0", "end")

    def listFiles(dir):
        global songList
        songList = []
        files = os.listdir(dir)
        for x, file in enumerate(files):
            filePath = chosenDirectory + "/" + file
            if not os.path.isdir(filePath):
                fileExt = file.split(".")[1]
                if fileExt == "mp3" or fileExt == "wav":
                    listBox.insert(x, file)
                    songList.append(filePath)

    listFiles(chosenDirectory)


class mediaControls:
    def curSelect(self, info):
        global cSong
        if listBox.curselection() != ():
            selected = listBox.get(listBox.curselection())
            if selected != cSong:
                cSong = selected
                cSongIndex = listBox.curselection()[0]
        self.playList()

    def playSong(self):
        if not player.playing:
            player.play()
        elif player.playing:
            player.pause()

    def playList(self):
        for song in songList:
            music = pyglet.media.load(song)
            print(music.duration)
            player.queue(music)
        self.playSong()

    def playNextSong(self):
        player.next_source()

    def playNewSong(self):
        global cSong
        global cSongIndex
        cSongIndex = cSongIndex + 1
        cSong = listBox.get(cSongIndex)
        self.playSong()
```

My expected result from this would be it cycling through all of the songs dequeuing them before moving on to the next, and not requiring intervention on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was expecting the queue to handle everything without realizing the pyglet.app.run() command is actually what sets all the events into motion. Without using that (since its blocking) I can just on_eos() to go ahead and call the next_source() function and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to remark on the use of `global` as you seem to have dealt with the issue of it not continuing to play. All uses of global can be eliminated by making the state part of the class. As when the application runs it makes an instance of that class that lives for the entire duration of the program run. Consider the following.

It is not working as you didn't include the entire script. `listBox` seems to be missing and should also be an instance member.

```
class mediaControls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chosenDirectory = ""
        self.cSong = ""
        self.cSongIndex = 0
        self.player = pyglet.media.Player()
        self.songList = []

    def chooseDirectory(self):
        self.chosenDirectory = chosenDirectory = tk.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/")
        lbl.configure(text=chosenDirectory)
        listBox.delete("0", "end")

        songList = []
        files = os.listdir(chosenDirectory)
        for x, file in enumerate(files):
            filePath = os.path.join(chosenDirectory, file)
            if not os.path.isdir(filePath):
                fileExt = file.split(".")[1]
                if fileExt == "mp3" or fileExt == "wav":
                    listBox.insert(x, file)
                    songList.append(filePath)
        self.songList = songList

    def curSelect(self, info):
        if listBox.curselection() != ():
            selected = listBox.get(listBox.curselection())
            if selected != self.cSong:
                self.cSong = selected
                self.cSongIndex = listBox.curselection()[0]
        self.playList()

    def playSong(self):
        if not self.player.playing:
            self.player.play()
        elif self.player.playing:
            self.player.pause()

    def playList(self):
        for song in self.songList:
            music = pyglet.media.load(song)
            print(music.duration)
            self.player.queue(music)
        self.playSong()

    def playNextSong(self):
        self.player.next_source()

    def playNewSong(self):
        self.cSongIndex = self.cSongIndex + 1
        self.cSong = listBox.get(self.cSongIndex)
        self.playSong()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely implement your suggestions.